# Does readr read_csv allow one to specific the specific file in a zip

Tags: r, readr

The readr package in the tidyverse has the option to automatically unpack a zip file and convert it to a tibble. But I have a zip file that holds multiple csv files. In the line of code below, SSPdataZip has three files in it. When I run it I get a warning "Multiple files in zip ..." and the name of the one it chooses. I know the name of the one I want but can't figure out how to tell read_csv what it is. Is there an option I'm missing?

```
temp <- readr::read_csv(SSPdataZip, col_names = TRUE, guess_max = 2000)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you can use `unz` to achieve this:

`readr::read_csv(unz(description = "SSPdataZip", filename = "FileName.csv"), col_names = TRUE, guess_max = 2000)`

Comment: One edit I would make for clarity sake is to say "... filename = "FileName.csv"). Sometimes a function has the filename first, but unz has the description, in this case the zip file name, first.

Comment: Good point. Corrected for the sake of being explicit. I assume everyone will investigate `unz` themselves by looking at the docs, figuring out the syntax.